# Create bookmark via selected text?

Tags: vba, ms-word, bookmarks

I'm trying to create a macro that will create a location bookmark at the location and the name of the selected text.

I have the code below, and it's saying the bookmark name is bad.

```
 Sub AddBookMark()

 Dim sText As String
 sText = Application.Selection.Text
 sText = Replace(sText, vbCrLf, "")
 sText = Replace(sText, Chr(10), " ")
 sText = Replace(sText, Chr(182), " ")

With ActiveDocument.Bookmarks
    .Add Range:=Selection.Range, Name:=sText
    .DefaultSorting = wdSortByName
    .ShowHidden = False
End With
End Sub
```

Is there any way to set the bookmark name as a variable based on the selected text?

Comment: It looks like it works, but if you select some text that has a blank afterwards it addes this symbol □ to the variable and it appears that is why it's not working . . how can i trim this out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

Tested it with a string like "**@#$1_qwerty@#@!# _1234**". The `CleanText` function will change it to "**qwerty_1234**"

A bookmark `Name` will accept `a-z/A-Z` as the 1st Character and `a-z/A-Z/0-1/_` as the rest.

```
Option Explicit

 Sub AddBookMark()
    Dim sText As String

    sText = CleanText(Application.Selection.Text)

    If sText = "" Then
        MsgBox "Invalid Name"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With ActiveDocument.Bookmarks
        .Add Range:=Selection.Range, Name:=sText
        .DefaultSorting = wdSortByName
        .ShowHidden = False
    End With
End Sub

Function CleanText(strInput As String) As String
    Dim i As Long, strTemp As String

    strInput = Trim(strInput)

    Do Until (Asc(Left(strInput, 1)) > 65 And Asc(Left(strInput, 1)) < 90) Or _
    (Asc(Left(strInput, 1)) > 97 And Asc(Left(strInput, 1)) < 122) Or Len(strInput) = 0
        Select Case Asc(Left(strInput, 1))
            Case 65 To 90, 97 To 122
            Case Else: strInput = Mid(strInput, 2)
        End Select
    Loop

    strTemp = Left(strInput, 1)

    For i = 2 To Len(strInput)
        Select Case Asc(Mid(strInput, i, 1))
            Case 65 To 90, 97 To 122, 95, 48 To 57
                strTemp = strTemp & Mid(strInput, i, 1)
        End Select
    Next
ExitF:
    CleanText = strTemp
End Function
```

Comment: Doesn't work. It's adding/converting the paragraph mark ¶ to a square symbol □ to the variable and that is what is stopping it. I've updated my code above where I've tried stripping out the paragraph mark and crlf's if they are found in the string to no avail.

Comment: anyway to trim the paragraph marks and any CRLF's or just check if the last character is a letter A/a-z/Z and if not then trim -1?

Comment: We can do that but then we will have to consider that we don't do `-1` but `- Actual` and also remove unwanted characters from the entire string. Let me give you an example.

Comment: Giving syntax errors on the Do Loop and the `strTemp = strTemp &amp; Mid(strInput, i, 1)`

Comment: Strange. I tested it again and it works... Did you copy the code correctly? If yes, can I see the document that you are trying it on?

Comment: Sorry, it is getting stuck on this line `Select Case Asc(Left(strInput, 1))` if multiple words are selected like "test here " . . if I do the "here " by itself it's fine

Comment: It works perfect!  Thanks!  Could you check this one out? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10899280/using-find-in-sharepoint-designer-vba]

Comment: unfortunately Sharepoint doesn't fall under one of my expertise :(

Comment: Is there anyway to convert -, /, or & marks to _ marks in this script?

Comment: Yes you can use the Replace() to replace those charaters.

Comment: Not sure how to do that as you set me up using case and i'm not familiar with case . . :S

Comment: I ended up doing this `strInput = Trim(strInput)
strInput = Replace(strInput, Chr(45), Chr(95))
strInput = Replace(strInput, Chr(38), Chr(95))
strInput = Replace(strInput, Chr(47), Chr(95))`

Comment: How can I throw a replace() in there to replace any chr except 65 To 90, 97 To 122, 95, 48 To 57 to chr(95)?

Comment: `Case 65 To 90, 97 To 122,95, 48 To 57` keep on adding with commas